# How to change the group address of a node in BLE Mesh Network?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, mesh-network

I have a BLE Mesh Network with two groups, Group A and Group B, Group A had two nodes in it and Group B has one node. I need to move a node from Group A to Group B. Is it possible to change the address of node after provisioning.